# Set dynamic PWA base routing in Angular 8

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I am developing an Angular PWA App. Below is my requirements.

Example: I have https://localhost.com website. So my PWA is taking me to this url after showing me the splash screen.

According to my requirements it should directly open https://localhost.com/user/login.

How can i achieve this. I am attaching my manifest file.

```
{
  "name": "buisness-card",
  "short_name": "buisness-card",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./user/login",
  "start_url": "./",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Angular's router to do the redirect?

Comment: Yes. I had used angular router

Comment: You should post your router code in the original question

Comment: Your question does not show any research effort towards using angulars well explained [routing](https://angular.io/guide/router). I suggest taking a look and update your question if any of it is unclear/ gives you trouble understanding.

Comment: Routing is working well without pwa. My question is when i open any of the url, let say xyz.com/fff then pwa should open xyz.com/fff.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the content of your app-routing.module.ts.

If you need domain.com to redirect to domain.com/user/login all you need to do is a redirectTo:

```
{ path: '<yourPath>', redirectTo: '<routeYouWantToRedirectTo>', pathMatch: 'full' }
```